# How to throw a custom error on a Firebase callable cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an API for my project and I'd like to throw custom error to catch it in my application.

Following [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode), I throw error with the code "unknown"

```
 throw new functions.https
  .HttpsError("unknown",
    "this is my error message", 
    {code :'myCustomCode', 
     message :'my custom message'}
   )
```

Then, I catch  with the right message and details, but with a"Internal Server Error"

[image]

I'am not sure it's the best way to create a clean API with cloud function.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With an `UNKNOWN` Functions error code you will always get a `500` HTTP response status code.

By using a more meaningful error code, among the ones proposed by the [Protocol specification for `https.onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) (and also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode)), you can get different response status codes, like, for example:

- 400 Bad Request for the `INVALID_ARGUMENT` Error Code
- 409 Conflict for the `ALREADY_EXISTS` Error Code
- etc...

The full list is to be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto). Have also a look at the following [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_format_status_codes) of the doc.

Comment: Actually I think I didn't undestand the "throwing error concept", I just want handle response with different behaviours (example : "User already exists", "no more coins today"). Throwing errors is mostly for development, right ?

Comment: "Throwing errors is mostly for development" -> Well, if you want to display to the user, in your front-end, some details of an error which occurred in the Callable Cloud Function you should throw an error (i.e. an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError` since it is a Callable CF) and use the code/message/details in the front-end. Now, you can decide that "no more coins today" is not an error but just a normal result of the business logic implemented by the CF. Then you would send a standard response back to the client.

Comment: Note that [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) are specifically designed **to be called from an app**. If you want to implement a "pure" REST API through Cloud Functions, better use a simple [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: Ok...Yes, I want display error to the user like "You cannot play twice today". This kind of error is, obviously, not  expected in status codes list. But, as I understand from your lastest  comments, it's usual to use other error code to catch this kind of exceptions, right ?

Comment: Actually, the question is : what FunctionErrorCode to use for Client Error ? the status code "ok" ?https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode

Comment: This is a classical debate... where is the frontier between a technical and functional error.... For example if you make a call to pass an order and there isn't enough money in your account, is it a failed precondition or a business logic case? You may find different opinions on the web, e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341732/should-http-status-codes-be-used-to-represent-business-logic-errors-on-a-server.

Comment: Personally I only send an error (`functions.https.HttpsError`) in case of technical/non-funtional error and sends back a standard response if there is a specific functional/business specific case (e.g. "not enough money").

Comment: "what FunctionErrorCode to use for Client Error" -> for  functional/business specific errors I don't send an error but a normal response, i.e. data that can be JSON encoded, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result. For example: `{result: "success"}` or `{result: "error", detail: "not enough money"}`. But again, others may do differently...